# How can I measure my data transfer?

Tags: web, hosting, data-transfer

I need to know how can I measure exactly my data transfer for a webpage that I am building. Can someone explain it in detail?

Also I need to know which server provider is good for my needs, I am building a webpage like Facebook, with a lot images and that kind of things.

Comment: If you're building a website like facebook, ask one of your few hundred programmers, maketers, etc.

Comment: @Daisetsu, really? Not a useful comment at all.  @Enrique The second half of your question is off-topic according to the site [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).  Please consider editing it out of the question.

Comment: @heavyd: it is kinda funny tho.  have you ever met a marketroid who can measure data transfer speeds? hahahahahaha!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but if you want to know how much a web browser needs to download to view one of your webpages, then check out [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), a firefox add-on that works with the excellent [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). That will show you in a nice graphical way how much is downloaded, how that's split up into different files, and the difference between when your cache is primed and empty.

Comment: I should mention that Chrome has this functionality built-in with its Developer tools.